# Passing Json data to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, api

I have successfully received a request result from API in HTML body request. I have three data set in an array and I need to pass only one, which is token to input type hidden.

This is the API response

```
{"status":"success","payment-token":"XqkcbkHAYdjNCIFdYnOG0QultKEi","notification-secret":"78e5394872218c6331b5b4e7d90b118b"}
```

Now I need to pass only the payment token (XqkcbkHAYdjNCIFdYnOG0QultKEi) to

`<input type="hidden" name="token" id="token">`

dynamically, that is after the autogenerating token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `data` is your variable containing your API response, try:

```
document.getElementById("token").value = data['payment-token'];
```